# Return default row, if no row found SQL

Tags: sql

I've got this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table]
WHERE ID > 18
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM [table]
```

I want to return the first row of the table if the above query does not return any rows. However, this returns two results sets, is there anyway I can combine this to only return one result set?

Comment: is there any known ID=0 or ID < 18?

Comment: @McNets Yes there is

Comment: You should not be using `TOP N` without an `ORDER BY` statement.  Without specifying an order, the result returned is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Siyual

Comment: Why do you want to return the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a EXISTS, ideally with a correlated query, but don't know your table structures.

```
SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM [table] WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ID > 18)
```

You should also add a ORDER BY if you use  TOP 1

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM [table]
WHERE ID > 18
UNION 
SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM [table] WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [table] WHERE ID>18) ORDER BY ID
```